# Parsing integer and boolean configurable variables in config.exs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have configuration where I want to pass boolean and integer variables as env.

```
BOOLEAN_VARIABLE=false
INTEGER_VARIABLE=5000
```

I also have default configuration that I want to set if given env variable is not found.
Here I am setting default value of `boolean_variable` to true and for `integer_variable` default value is 2000.

```
boolean_variable =
  case System.get_env("BOOLEAN_VARIABLE") do
    "false" -> false
    _ -> true
  end

integer_variable =
  case System.get_env("INTEGER_VARIABLE") do
    nil -> 2000
    value -> String.to_integer(value)
  end
```

I have ended up with dozens of calls in configuration while parsing these variables in `config.exs`. I was curious if there is better way to have this configuration.

Comment: Are you using this in conjunction with releases?

Comment: This is a way am providing secret values and configurable values like interval time for scheduler in my application. I am using this along with release so I can change these values on build as configuration itself. Also, here i only mentioned `config.exs` but these values differ b/w different env from `qa` to `staging`. I hope this answer's your question.

Comment: in such cases, you should define all your default values in `config.exs` and the updated ones in other configs. This way other configs will override the values of config if needed.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. This approach sure would help in having minimal configurations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save them as environment variables.
You can have a `.env` or some other file where you store environment variables.
Then in your `config` files, you can read them + you can set the default value.

Here is an example.

```
.env file
BOOLEAN_VARIABLE=false
INTEGER_VARIABLE=4000
```

[`System.get_env/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html?#get_env/2) function can have string based default value as the second argument.

In your elixir code you can do:

```
System.get_env("BOOLEAN_VARIABLE", "false") |> Config.parse_boolean
System.get_env("INTEGER_VARIABLE", "2000") |> Config.parse_integer # or String.to_integer
```

The benefit of this approach is:

- Your configurable variables are read from environment
- It's easy to change value directly in .env file and then just source it with `source .env` command.
- For docker & docker-compose, you can directly set the variables.
- Your elixir & phoenix app will stay modular.
- You can avoid compile-time dependencies which can lead to very unpredictable behaviour in different environments.

Comment: Thanks arpit, I appreciate your detailed explanation.

Comment: If you are on  unix based system (linux or mac), you can use tools like  auto-env.
I use a zsh-plugin (`zpm-zsh/autoenv`) that sets the environment variable when we `cd` into the elixir-project.